# Eclipse Photon (4.8.0) RCP application plug-ins loading issue

Tags: eclipse, loading, rcp, photon

I am updating Eclipse RCP application from Indigo(3.7.0) to Photon(4.8.0), and I am facing issue with loading plug-ins.

Eclipse Photon(4.8.0) RCP Application is not able to load Plugins which are copied to the plugin directory unless bundles-info is updated with the plug-in details.

This was working fine in the Indigo version.

Could someone help me in understanding what all needs to be modified apart from updating the required plugins to the latest version ( in my case, to Eclipse photon 4.8)

I am getting an error when I try to launch the RCP application using the existing *.exe and config.ini files Error is displayed as "Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini)."

In Config.ini , the osgi.bundles value is specified as osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.core.runtime@start,\ org.eclipse.equinox.common@start,\ org.eclipse.update.configurator,\ org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86

Can I make any changes to load plugins automatically?

Comment: You can still use `org.eclipse.update.configurator`, but it seems you using [p2](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/p2/) where you copy plug-ins into the `dropins` instead of directly into `plugins` folder (or even better using the installation wizard to install the features from a p2 update site).

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: I want to use plug-ins directory and I am using **eclipse.core.runtime** instead of **simpleconfigurator** in **config.ini** file
`osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start,org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start,org.eclipse.core.runtime@start`

Comment: May i know the issue which you are facing? I mean error which you are getting while downloading the plugins. You can download the plugins from the eclipse or any other site and add those to eclipse configurations( I dont remember the exact folder name directory) directory and restart eclipse.

Comment: A huge lot of  Edit is made to the question providing many details, Could you recheck, If this info can help you

Comment: Could you please also show what is in the log before, starting with `!SESSION`? If you use Java 9 or 10, do you have the `-vmarg` `--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM`?